# Filter relation using parameter on model - Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model with relations, and need to filter this relations depending on request parameter.

On controller I get all properties with his owners (a property can have several owners, and vice versa).

Property controller:

```
$property= Property::query()
                            ->when($request->search, function($query, $search) {
                                        $query->where('name','like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                              ->orWhere('name2','like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                              ->orWhere('city','like', '%'.$search.'%');
                            })                                        
                            ->select(['id', 'name', 'published'])
                            ->with(['photo', 'owner', 'destiny'])->get();
```

And in property model:

```
public function owner(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Owner::class,
        'rel_owners_properties'
    )->select(['owner.id', 'owner.nombre', 'owner.nombre_empresa']);
}
```

Now, if I have a $request->ownerId value in controller, I need to filter only the properties that this owner has.

I have tried with something like this, but I receive all the properties without any owner:

```
$property= Property::query()
                            ->when($request->search, function($query, $search) {
                                        $query->where('name','like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                        ->orWhere('name2','like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                        ->orWhere('city','like', '%'.$search.'%');
                            })                                        
                            ->select(['id', 'name', 'published'])
                            ->with([
                                   'photo',
                                   'owner' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                                            $query->where(['owner_id' => $request->ownerId]);
                                        },

                                    'destiny'
                                    ])->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter by a relationship you need to use `whereHas`:

```
$property = Property::query()
    ->when($request->search, function ($query, $search) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('name2', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    })
    ->select(['id', 'name', 'published'])
    ->whereHas('owner', function ($query) use ($request) {
         $query->where('id', $request->ownerId); 
     });
    ->with([
        'photo',
        'owner'
        'destiny'
    ])->get();
```